Coupling the Optionality of two types
Example Code
I = TypeVar("I", bound=Optional[Iterable])
O = TypeVar("O", bound=Optional[Mappable])


class Worker(Generic[I, O]):
    @abstractmethod
    def do_work(self, input: I) -> O:
        pass


worker = Worker[list, dict]()
worker_with_optional = Worker[Optional[list], Optional[dict]]()
worker_bad_types = Worker[Optional[list], dict]()

The actual code in the example may seem a bit contrived, but it was the best way I could think to abstractly represent my problem. What I'm struggling to do is set up TypeVars for the input to Generic that would allow users to create worker and worker_with_optional but not worker_bad_types.
The concept that I'm struggling to put into code is the relatedness of the two input types. I want to require that I and O are both Optional or they are both required to have a value.
The best workaround for the functionality I want would be to make two versions of the class like this:
I = TypeVar("I", bound=Iterable)
O = TypeVar("O", bound=Mappable)


class Worker(Generic[I, O]):
    @abstractmethod
    def do_work(self, input: I) -> O:
        pass

class WorkerWithOptional(Generic[I, O]):
    @abstractmethod
    def do_work(self, input: Optional[I]) -> Optional[O]:
        pass

worker = Worker[list, dict]()
worker_with_optional = WorkerWithOptional[list, dict]()
# worker_bad_types now has a type error because None is not Iterable
worker_bad_types = Worker[Optional[int], str]()

This approach accomplishes the type restrictions I want, but I'd rather not make two copies of my class to account for this. Is there a way to relate the Optionality of the types passed into Generic so that they always match?

I can't reproduce your problem in edit: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=1.10.1&python=3.12&flags=strict&gist=eddfe3ece0e8b2e3cd44385d98ba5392. Aren't you trying to reuse previous O defined somewhere earlier? Never is exactly that "StrawManType" - Never is uninhabited type, so x | Never == x by definition.

Interesting. My bad, I should've tested it in the mypy playground. You're right. mypy handles the Answer code correctly. I had tested it in my local environment and it was actually pylance (version 2024.7.1) that was giving me the error: Type "Never" cannot be assigned to type variable "O@TestClass"   Type "Never" is incompatible with constrained type variable "O@TestClass"PylancereportInvalidTypeArguments. It's a bit frustrating that pylance doesn't handle this well.

pyright Playground
mypy playground

You can remove the restriction altogether. It's a bit worse for clarity and safety, but you have to pay something for supporting several typecheckers. Playground

(and consider opening a pyright ticket if it isn't there yet - Eric must be fed up with my ideas, but this really looks like a bug)

I've opened a ticket with the pyright project. You can follow the thread here: https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/8432

I = TypeVar("I", bound=Iterable)
O = TypeVar("O", bound=Mapping)

T = TypeVar("T", None, Never)

class BaseWorker(Generic[I, O, T]):
    @abstractmethod
    def do_work(self, input: I | T) -> O | T:
        pass

Worker: TypeAlias = BaseWorker[I, O, Never]
WorkerWithOptional: TypeAlias = BaseWorker[I, O, None]

Never is uninstantiable, meaning that I | Never simplifies to I. We take advantage of this to allow your optionality to be controlled by the parameter T.
If you run the mypy playground of the below code, you can see that of the 4 test cases, only #2 receives a type error as expected.
class TestWorker(Worker[list[int], dict[int, int]]):
    def do_work(self, input: list[int]) -> dict[int, int]:
        return {x: 1 for x in input}

class TestWorkerWithOptional(WorkerWithOptional[list[int], dict[int, int]]):
    def do_work(self, input: list[int] | None) -> dict[int, int] | None:
        return None if input is None else {x: 1 for x in input}

worker = TestWorker()
worker_w_opt = TestWorkerWithOptional()

worker.do_work([1])        # 1
worker.do_work(None)       # 2

worker_w_opt.do_work([1])  # 3
worker_w_opt.do_work(None) # 4

